# Beautifulsoup scraping javascript table issues csv

Tags: javascript, python, csv, web, scrape

I currently have a script that will generate a list of urls and names from a base URL, and a script that will use the link that is in the urls list to give me the data i need but im struggling with how i should go about creating a loop that grabs the url from the first row, runs the second script and then saves the file as column 2+3 in the first file that contained the urls.

Here are my two scripts and the data they output.

```
import io
import requests
import operator
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
url = 'http://arizonascaleracers.liverc.com/results'
response = get(url)
print(response.text[:500])
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
type(html_soup)
race_tables = html_soup.find_all('table', {'class':'table table-hover entry_list_data'})[2]

output_rows = []
for row in race_tables.find('tbody').find_all("tr")[1:]:
    col = row.find_all("td")
    output_row = []
    for td in col:


        if td.find(racename=''):
            racename = ''.join('blank')
        if td.find(suburl=''):
            suburl = ''.join('blank')
        if td.find(time=''):
            time = ''.join('blank')

        else:
            suburl = row.find("a")['href']
            racename = col[0].text
            time = col[1].text
        output_row.append(td)

    output_rows.append(output_row)

with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(output_rows)
```

The output from this script is...

```
"<td><a class=""block"" href=""/results/?p=view_race_result&amp;id=2227665""><i class=""fa fa-trophy""></i> Race 6: Modified Touring Car (Modified Touring Car A-Main)</a></td>","<td>Nov 23, 2019 at 2:39pm</td>"
"<td><a class=""block"" href=""/results/?p=view_race_result&amp;id=2227664""><i class=""fa fa-trophy""></i> Race 5: 17.5 Super Stock Touring Car (17.5 Super Stock Touring Car A-Main)</a></td>","<td>Nov 23, 2019 at 2:31pm</td>"
"<td><a class=""block"" href=""/results/?p=view_race_result&amp;id=2227666""><i class=""fa fa-trophy""></i> Race 4: Pro GT (Pro GT A-Main)</a></td>","<td>Nov 23, 2019 at 2:17pm</td>"
"<td><a class=""block"" href=""/results/?p=view_race_result&amp;id=2227662""><i class=""fa fa-trophy""></i> Race 3: USGT 21.5 (USGT 21.5 A-Main)</a></td>","<td>Nov 23, 2019 at 2:10pm</td>"
"<td><a class=""block"" href=""/results/?p=view_race_result&amp;id=2227663""><i class=""fa fa-trophy""></i> Race 2: 1-12 Open Modified (1-12 Open Modified A-Main)</a></td>","<td>Nov 23, 2019 at 2:03pm</td>"
"<td><a class=""block"" href=""/results/?p=view_race_result&amp;id=2227661""><i class=""fa fa-trophy""></i> Race 1: VTA (VTA A-Main)</a></td>","<td>Nov 23, 2019 at 1:52pm</td>"

"<td><a class=""block"" href=""/results/?p=view_race_result&amp;id=2227120""><i class=""fa fa-trophy""></i> Race 6: Modified Touring Car (Modified Touring Car  (Heat 1/1))</a></td>","<td>Nov 23, 2019 at 1:22pm</td>"
"<td><a class=""block"" href=""/results/?p=view_race_result&amp;id=2227119""><i class=""fa fa-trophy""></i> Race 5: 17.5 Super Stock Touring Car (17.5 Super Stock Touring Car  (Heat 1/1))</a></td>","<td>Nov 23, 2019 at 1:14pm</td>"
"<td><a class=""block"" href=""/results/?p=view_race_result&amp;id=2227118""><i class=""fa fa-trophy""></i> Race 4: Pro GT (Pro GT  (Heat 1/1))</a></td>","<td>Nov 23, 2019 at 1:06pm</td>"
"<td><a class=""block"" href=""/results/?p=view_race_result&amp;id=2227117""><i class=""fa fa-trophy""></i> Race 3: USGT 21.5 (USGT 21.5  (Heat 1/1))</a></td>","<td>Nov 23, 2019 at 12:58pm</td>"
"<td><a class=""block"" href=""/results/?p=view_race_result&amp;id=2227116""><i class=""fa fa-trophy""></i> Race 2: 1-12 Open Modified (1-12 Open Modified  (Heat 1/1))</a></td>","<td>Nov 23, 2019 at 12:51pm</td>"
"<td><a class=""block"" href=""/results/?p=view_race_result&amp;id=2227115""><i class=""fa fa-trophy""></i> Race 1: VTA (VTA  (Heat 1/1))</a></td>","<td>Nov 23, 2019 at 12:40pm</td>"

"<td><a class=""block"" href=""/results/?p=view_race_result&amp;id=2226732""><i class=""fa fa-trophy""></i> Race 6: Modified Touring Car (Modified Touring Car  (Heat 1/1))</a></td>","<td>Nov 23, 2019 at 12:18pm</td>"
"<td><a class=""block"" href=""/results/?p=view_race_result&amp;id=2226731""><i class=""fa fa-trophy""></i> Race 5: 17.5 Super Stock Touring Car (17.5 Super Stock Touring Car  (Heat 1/1))</a></td>","<td>Nov 23, 2019 at 12:11pm</td>"
"<td><a class=""block"" href=""/results/?p=view_race_result&amp;id=2226730""><i class=""fa fa-trophy""></i> Race 4: Pro GT (Pro GT  (Heat 1/1))</a></td>","<td>Nov 23, 2019 at 12:03pm</td>"
"<td><a class=""block"" href=""/results/?p=view_race_result&amp;id=2226729""><i class=""fa fa-trophy""></i> Race 3: USGT 21.5 (USGT 21.5  (Heat 1/1))</a></td>","<td>Nov 23, 2019 at 11:55am</td>"
"<td><a class=""block"" href=""/results/?p=view_race_result&amp;id=2226728""><i class=""fa fa-trophy""></i> Race 2: 1-12 Open Modified (1-12 Open Modified  (Heat 1/1))</a></td>","<td>Nov 23, 2019 at 11:47am</td>"
"<td><a class=""block"" href=""/results/?p=view_race_result&amp;id=2226727""><i class=""fa fa-trophy""></i> Race 1: VTA (VTA  (Heat 1/1))</a></td>","<td>Nov 23, 2019 at 11:37am</td>"

"<td><a class=""block"" href=""/results/?p=view_race_result&amp;id=2226250""><i class=""fa fa-trophy""></i> Race 6: Modified Touring Car (Modified Touring Car  (Heat 1/1))</a></td>","<td>Nov 23, 2019 at 11:16am</td>"
"<td><a class=""block"" href=""/results/?p=view_race_result&amp;id=2226249""><i class=""fa fa-trophy""></i> Race 5: 17.5 Super Stock Touring Car (17.5 Super Stock Touring Car  (Heat 1/1))</a></td>","<td>Nov 23, 2019 at 11:08am</td>"
"<td><a class=""block"" href=""/results/?p=view_race_result&amp;id=2226251""><i class=""fa fa-trophy""></i> Race 4: Pro GT (Pro GT  (Heat 1/1))</a></td>","<td>Nov 23, 2019 at 11:00am</td>"
"<td><a class=""block"" href=""/results/?p=view_race_result&amp;id=2226247""><i class=""fa fa-trophy""></i> Race 3: USGT 21.5 (USGT 21.5  (Heat 1/1))</a></td>","<td>Nov 23, 2019 at 10:52am</td>"
"<td><a class=""block"" href=""/results/?p=view_race_result&amp;id=2226248""><i class=""fa fa-trophy""></i> Race 2: 1-12 Open Modified (1-12 Open Modified  (Heat 1/1))</a></td>","<td>Nov 23, 2019 at 10:42am</td>"
"<td><a class=""block"" href=""/results/?p=view_race_result&amp;id=2226246""><i class=""fa fa-trophy""></i> Race 1: VTA (VTA  (Heat 1/1))</a></td>","<td>Nov 23, 2019 at 10:31am</td>"
```

Then my second script..

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request as urllib2
html = urllib2.urlopen('http://arizonascaleracers.liverc.com/results/?p=view_race_result&id=2227665')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', {"class":"table table-striped race_result"})
for row in table.find('tbody').find_all("tr", recursive=False):
    col = row.find_all("td")

    FinishPos = col[0].text.strip()
    DriverInfo = col[1].text.strip()
    DI = row.find('span', class_ = 'driver_name')
    Qual = col[2].text.strip()
    test = col[3].text
    LapsTime = col[4].text
    Behind = col[5].text
    Fastest = col[6].text
    Avg_Lap = col[7].text
    Avg_Top_5 = col[8].text
    Avg_Top_10  = col[9].text
    Avg_Top_15 = col[10].text
    Top_3_Consecutive = col[11].text

    DI = DI.text

    print(FinishPos, Qual, DI, test, LapsTime, Behind, Fastest, Avg_Lap)
```

and the output here is...

```
1 1 GABE HARVELL 24/5:04.408 --- 12.481 12.83912.839 12.59312.593
2 3 JOHNATHAN LEE 24/5:09.287 4.879 12.583 13.01113.011 12.65512.655
3 4 BRAD TOFFELMIRE 24/5:12.110 2.823 12.520 13.11813.118 12.71012.710
4 2 JACK KLOEBER 23/5:09.212 1 Lap 13.028 13.61013.610 13.09713.097
5 5 BILL CLINE 22/5:02.867 1 Lap 13.177 13.89813.898 13.28713.287
6 6 TIMOTHY SCHMUCK 22/5:03.815 0.948 12.919 13.92713.927 13.13913.139
7 7 CRAIG NELSON 21/5:08.304 1 Lap 13.713 14.82414.824 13.95713.957
```

now im thinking i need to create a loop and loop these through calling the columns for the input and output something like....

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

contents = []
with open('output.csv','r') as csvf:
    urls = csv.reader(csvf)[:0]
    for url in urls:
        html = urllib2.urlopen('http://arizonascaleracers.liverc.com'+(url))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        table = soup.find('table', {"class":"table table-striped race_result"})
        for row in table.find('tbody').find_all("tr", recursive=False):
            col = row.find_all("td")

            FinishPos = col[0].text.strip()
            DriverInfo = col[1].text.strip()
            DI = row.find('span', class_ = 'driver_name')
            Qual = col[2].text.strip()
            test = col[3].text
            LapsTime = col[4].text
            Behind = col[5].text
            Fastest = col[6].text
            Avg_Lap = col[7].text
            Avg_Top_5 = col[8].text
            Avg_Top_10  = col[9].text
            Avg_Top_15 = col[10].text
            Top_3_Consecutive = col[11].text

            DI = DI.text


        output_rows.append(output_row)
        with open('col[1]+[2].csv', 'w') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            writer.writerows(output_rows)
```

Obviously this last piece doesnt work and i cant seem to find any answer on how to get this done.

What im trying to end up with is this data.

```
1 1 GABE HARVELL 24/5:04.408 --- 12.481 12.83912.839 12.59312.593
2 3 JOHNATHAN LEE 24/5:09.287 4.879 12.583 13.01113.011 12.65512.655
3 4 BRAD TOFFELMIRE 24/5:12.110 2.823 12.520 13.11813.118 12.71012.710
4 2 JACK KLOEBER 23/5:09.212 1 Lap 13.028 13.61013.610 13.09713.097
5 5 BILL CLINE 22/5:02.867 1 Lap 13.177 13.89813.898 13.28713.287
6 6 TIMOTHY SCHMUCK 22/5:03.815 0.948 12.919 13.92713.927 13.13913.139
7 7 CRAIG NELSON 21/5:08.304 1 Lap 13.713 14.82414.824 13.95713.957
```

but for each url. That data there is for a single url.

```
"<td><a class=""block"" href=""/results/?p=view_race_result&amp;id=2227665""><i class=""fa fa-trophy""></i> Race 6: Modified Touring Car (Modified Touring Car A-Main)</a></td>","<td>Nov 23, 2019 at 2:39pm</td>"
```

My end goal is to have this run on sundays (we race on saturdays) scrape the base url for the suburls and then scrape each individual suburl for the data that looks similar to above, and save it as the race name and time. something like

```
Race 6: Modified Touring Car (Modified Touring Car A-Main)Nov 23, 2019.csv
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you describe the data you need a bit more clearly? What's the expected result? Thanks.

Comment: I went ahead and added some additional detail, let me know if that makes more sense. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like script 2 produces this output though, right?

Comment: script two does, but i want to automate rolling through the urls and generating the data, i need to extract the data from script 1 to fill in to script two as the input and output.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little bit of refactoring that should help you get your scraped data into the CSV form.  It eliminates the interim CSV file and simply loops through each of the race entries URLs, pulls the text, and then puts the resulting data in a namedtuple data structure for easier modification.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# functionality of first script
import sys
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import namedtuple

base_url = 'http://arizonascaleracers.liverc.com'
response = requests.get('{}/results/?p=view_event&id={}'.format(base_url, sys.argv[1]))
#response = requests.get('{}/results'.format(base_url))

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
race_tables = html_soup.find_all('table', {'class':'table table-hover entry_list_data'})[2]

REGEX_RACENAME = re.compile(' ?Race \d: [\w \.\-]+(\([\w \.\-\(\/\)]+\))')

Car = namedtuple('Car', ['FinishPos', 'DriverInfo', 'Qual', 'LapsTime', 'Fastest', 'AvgLap', 'AvgTop5', 'AvgTop10', 'AvgTop15', 'Top3Consecutive'])
races = []

class Race:
    def __init__(self, name, time, race_id):
        self.name = newname
        self.time = time
        self.id = race_id
        self.positions = []

    def __str__(self):
        retval = ''
        for p in self.positions:
            line = '{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|\n'.format(p.FinishPos, p.Qual, p.DriverInfo, p.LapsTime, p.Fastest, p.AvgLap, p.AvgTop10, p.AvgTop15, p.Top3Consecutive, self.name, self.time)
            retval += line
        return retval

for row in race_tables.find('tbody').find_all("tr")[1:]:
    col = row.find("a", href=True)
    try:
        racename = col.text
        newname = REGEX_RACENAME.match(racename).group(1)[1:][:-1]
    except AttributeError:
        continue
    else:
        href = col.get('href')
        timestamp = row.find_all("td")[-1].text
        r = Race(newname, timestamp, href)

        response = requests.get('{}{}'.format(base_url, href))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        table = soup.find('table', {"class":"table table-striped race_result"})
        for entry in table.find('tbody').find_all("tr", recursive=False):
            col = entry.find_all("td")

            FinishPos = col[0].text.strip()
            DriverInfo = entry.find('span', class_ = 'driver_name').text
            Qual = col[2].text.strip()
            LapsTime = col[4].text
            Fastest = col[6].text
            Avg_Lap = col[7].text
            Avg_Top_5 = col[8].text
            Avg_Top_10  = col[9].text
            Avg_Top_15 = col[10].text
            Top_3_Consecutive = col[11].text
            c = Car(FinishPos, DriverInfo, Qual, LapsTime, Fastest, Avg_Lap, Avg_Top_5, Avg_Top_10, Avg_Top_15, Top_3_Consecutive)
            r.positions.append(c)
        races.append(r)

# second script

with open('output', 'a') as outputfile:
    print(len(races))
    for r in races:
        #print(r.name)
        #print(str(r))
        outputfile.write(str(r)) # add in different fields to be outputted to CSV as desired
```

Good luck with your project!